# Font-awesome icons in github wiki

Tags: github, wiki, font-awesome

How would I display a Font-Awesome icon in a github wiki?

I tried to link to the source from the Font-Awesome site, but it just creates a link

eg:

```
| Element | Icon Name | Icon Image|
| ------- | ----------| ----------|
| chart | fa-line-chart | http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/line-chart |
| trash | fa-trash | http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/trash |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want the visual and don't care how it is delivered you can keep it github and link to **encharms** repo using an `<img>`

I guess if you were worried about the repo disappearing you could fork your own version with just the icons you need.

`|a|b|`[image: trash]`|`

Most icons are available in most sizes.

Not got the reputation to post an image example yet!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, by design.

*Font Awesome*, similar to *Twitter Bootstrap* requires the `class` attribute,
which is [not allowed](http://github.com/github/markup#html-sanitization) with
any element.

Answer (score 1):

*Quoting [Github Markup Docs](https://github.com/github/markup)*

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes.

Hence, it's not possible at the moment.